# managing large number of CSS variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I'm looking to expose a dynamic color palette (~300 entries) in an app as CSS variables.  Today it's managed entirely in JS -- as content is generated, the palette is applied directly (e.g. by setting style='rgb(...)' to new elements).  But when the palette updates, only new content uses the new palette.  Obviously CSS variables solve this.

I'm already using CSS variables for other features, and the logic works.  Roughly, the html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    :root {
      --my-var: ...default value...;
      --some-other-var: ...;
    }
  </style>
</head>
</html>
```

With the corresponding runtime JS code like:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--my-var', 'new-value');
```

When that runs, it updates the `<html>` element, so it now looks like:

```
<html style="--my-var:new-value">
...same code as above...
```

If I add ~300 new variables, the `<html>` node is unreadable in DOM inspectors and it hurts my delicate sensibilities.  The question is, how best to manage this w/out messing up performance (assuming attaching ~300 variables to the html node doesn't already tank the perf) ?

I could create a dedicated `<style>` tag and generate the text content to have the `:root {...}` code, but the overhead of that seems much higher for the browser -- it'd have to reparse everything from scratch and recalculate all the styles.  Even just having a sep `<style>` node would probably be preferable to stuffing `<html>` so I could have a "color palette node" to manage the noise, but setting properties on a style element doesn't (seem to) work -- the properties get set, but have no effect.

Am I just SOL ?  I'm not interested in "just use XXX framework and all that ails you will be cured", unless those frameworks are used to illustrate the underlying CSS/JS behavior for how they don't poo all over DOM nodes.

Comment: are you trying to create something like a theme?

Comment: Of sorts, but if you're going to suggest that I create different CSS files with each theme speced out and then have people pick between those, that's not what I'm looking for here.  My current focus is on color palettes, but I have more things I could stuff into variables, so the question of how to manage large number of CSS vars effectively still stands.